# Upload struct to server With Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, alamofire

I want to upload an image URL to my server using Alamofire. I have a struct that holds my image URL and a CGRect that looks like this on the framework:

```
public struct TGImage {

    private(set) var url: String? 
    private(set) var crop: CGRect

    public init(url: String, crop: CGRect) {
        self.url = url
        self.crop = crop
    }
}
```

and like this in the `viewDidLoad()` of my project:

```
let tgImageURL = TGImage(url: "http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/model-walks-the-runway-at-the-tory-burch-fw17-show-during-new-york-picture-id635259314", crop: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 499, height: 358))
```

My server takes in that struct and returns json, but I don't know how to upload it to the server. This is what I have so far for the function on the framework side of things:

```
public func detectBoxes(image: TGImage) {

    let user = "key_wcjRv0QAasd76W83tZHrIH1Y70U"
    let password = ""

    var headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    Alamofire.request("http://api-dev.websiteURL.co/v1/prediction/tag", headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

and on the project side:

```
tg.detectBoxes(image: tgImageURL)
```

Comment: 1. Which format are planning to use to send the struct to the server? Your request's content type is JSON 2. I don't see any use of image in detectBoxes - it seems to me that you should have transform your struct to JSON string and then send it to the server

Comment: @inspector_60 do i really have to transform to JSON? could i potentially upload the url and an array of 4 numbers representing the "crop" variable aka (width, height, x, y)? i was really asking for the acutal function. how would i implement the actual code

Comment: It depend on your server implementation, the client and the server needs to agree upon a mutual "language" and usually it JSON or XML, so you need to serialize your object to JSON or XML. It seems in your code that it should be JSON. 
Any way serializing your struct is not difficult task, you can use the build it JSON serialization which is a bit cumbersome (on Swift 4 its been improved) or use open source library like SwiftyJSON [link] (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: @inspector_60  
cool. so once i convert, lets say, a struct to json, is there a way to send a json string?

Comment: of course... and Alamofire can really help you with that (beside the options I mentioned above) go to Alamofire documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: @inspector_60 thanks man. if u write an answer w all the info u told me and with the specific part of the alamofire documentation u think i should look at ill give u the check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client and server needs to agree upon a mutual "language" and usually it's JSON or XML, so you need to serialize your object to JSON or XML. It seems in your code that it should be JSON since you indicated in your header that the content type is JSON. (and no one really uses xml anymore)

You also need to agree (with server) which http method (post or get) the server expect you to use this will determine where you will send the data (`post` method - on body or `get` method - on headers)

Use [Alamofire's json-encoding](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#json-encoding) documentation to see examples and instructions of how to send the request properly (using `post`)

Any way, serializing your struct is not difficult task,
You can use Swift's build it JSON serialization with `NSJSONSerialization` which is a bit cumbersome or use open source library like [SwiftyJSON](http://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Here is an example of how to use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
func Serialization(object: AnyObject)  -> String{
    do {
        let stringData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(object, options: [])
        if let string = String(data: stringData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
            return string
        }
    }catch _ {

    }
    return "{\"element\":\"jsonError\"}"
}
```